# First repeating character | Runtime

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity

The goal is to find the first recurring character in a string.

Presented in the video below are two algorithms, the first naive one has time complexity n squared. The second algorithm (starting at 2:34 in the video) runs in O(n). But I don't see why, as each new char needs to be compared to all previous chars in the table, which will lead to a total runtime of n squared again. Maybe here the assumptions about the hardware (Turing machine) are important?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJdiM-muYqc

Comment: It's not a valid question to assign a video to watch. Please summarize here the algorithms presented in the video.

Comment: What does "recurring character" mean? Does it mean the character has at least two occurrences? Or does it mean it should reappear periodically?

Comment: `Hash` based collection, (`HashSet`, `HashMap`, `HashTable`, `Dictionary` etc.) has `O(1)` time complexity for either `Add` or `Contains` operation when we have a good hash function. So, the overall complexity is `n * O(1) == O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

**But I don't see why, as each new char needs to be compared to all previous chars in the table**

The trick is to compare a character to all characters that you have seen in time that is not linear in the number of characters that you've examined. There are multiple ways of doing it, such as using a hash table or a balanced tree. Hash set lookup yields constant time, while a balanced tree lookup yields a log<sub>2</sub>n time.

To illustrate this point, consider a string consisting only of digits. There are ten possible digits, so the test for "have I seen this digit before" takes at most ten steps, even if you have examined a string of a million digits. The same thing can be done with all characters.

Hash tables take this even further, because they drop the requirement for the number of possibilities to be bounded by something relatively small. Same goes for balanced trees, although the lookup becomes logarithmic.

Comment: Yeah the reason is that there is only a finite amount of possible characters

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer. The reason is the finite number of possible characters. So the comparison will always only take a constant amount of time.

Comment: I'd just delete the whole post. To a future reader it says only:  "I watched a video about algorithms, was puzzled for a moment, then I worked it out".